# How can I assign a tabindex value to all elements starting with a specific element?

Tags: jquery

The following code snippet assigns a `tabindex` value to all elements on a page starting with the first element on the page. I'd like to do the same thing but rather than beginning with the first element on the page I'd like to begin with a specific element and then loop through the remaining elements.

**Edit** 
Additional Requirement: I'd like to chose the first element by its id attribute then loop through the rest.

```
$(function(){
    var tabindex = 1;
    $('input,select').each(function() {
        if (this.type != "hidden") {
            var $input = $(this);
            $input.attr("tabindex", tabindex);
            tabindex++;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: And what is the specific element?

Comment: It could be either a dropdown box or a textbox.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:gt(n)` psedo selector. The following will assign a tab index starting with the 10th element:

```
$(function(){
    var tabindex = 1;
    $(':input:not([type=hidden])').filter('input,select').filter(':gt(8)').each(function() {
         var $input = $(this);
         $input.attr("tabindex", tabindex++);
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

As for the ID requirement, you would have to loop through the elements and elect to change those that meet the requirement:

```
$(function(){
    var tabindex = 1;
    $(':input:not([type=hidden])').filter('input,select').each(function() {
        if( $(this).is('#desired_id') || tabindex > 1 ) {
            var $input = $(this);
            $input.attr("tabindex", tabindex++);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'd rather call the element by id.

Comment: And what, exactly, do you mean by that?

Comment: I'd like to chose the first element by its id attribute then loop through the rest.

Comment: Please put all your requirements in your question and let us know when they are all in. Thanks.

Comment: @navig8tr That doesn't make much sense. Are you implying that you want them to share a common parent element with an `id`, like: `$('#element-id').find('input:gt(8), select:gt(8)').each(function(..)`..?

Comment: @Josh Crozier: I'd rather not use a number at all. Do you think that's possible?

Comment: @navig8tr You should post your HTML. There are many possible solutions. Depending on your markup, you may want something like `.nextAll()` or `.nextUntil()`..

Comment: @PeterKA: So you're update would set `desired_id` to one and the rest of the elements sequentially greater than one?

Comment: Ok I'll give it a shot.